# How to make listbox item represent a number and send to a textbox

Tags: c#

I am making a calculator for an assignment and I have been stuck on figuring out how to do it.I have a listbox with days from day 1 - 14 and I want them to represent the number that they are based on the day.So lets say my parking is 20$/day and i clicked on 3 days the result  should comes out to 60$ in a textbox.

Ive tried this but it only works if anything with double is deleted or else it comes out as an error which is not what i want and it is only a string

```
        string a = listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        textBox9.Text = a;
```

-

```
                private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Add(1+" Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(2 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(3 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(4 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(5 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(6 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(7 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(8 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(9 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(10 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(11 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(12 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(13 + " Days(s)");
        listBox1.Items.Add(14 + " Days(s)");





    }
    private void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i <= listBox1.SelectedIndex; i++)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());


        }



    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double parking = 0;



        parking = double.Parse(textBox8.Text);

        string a = listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        textBox9.Text = a;

        //Im trying to figure out along the lines of textbox9.text = parking * listbox3.selectedItem
    }
```

Comment: It's not C; `private` isn't a keyword in C.  It's not C++; you can't use `private` where it is used in the code.  It must be C#.  Don't use multiple language tags without a far better reason to do so than is apparent in this question.

Comment: You have the logic right there in the comment - convert it to code step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that you could just do something like:

```
textBox9.Text = parking * (listBox3.SelectedIndex + 1)
```

Check out the [SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property here.